# how to convert html data into an excel or PDF and attach it for download?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a financial website where on click on pdf or excel sheet i need to convert existing data into an PDF and it should get downloaded. Can you help me how to start about this ??
Can it be done through scripting or does it require JAVA ??

Thanks

Comment: you have excel or pdf inside html code? and you're not importing it from somewhere else? o.o

Comment: I have static data in my html .. i need this in excel or PDF on click of its icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to convert it into pdf, kindly refer mozilla plugin called page saver, a simple command like "firefox --display localhost:2.0 -saveimage" will convert HTML to image file, which can than be converted into pdf easily.

Comment: Does it convert data which is populating in the front end from backend into an excel sheet ??? ..
is it compatible in all browsers ??

Comment: sorry unfortunately it won't, you need to pass HTML as an argument in it, and it will save it as an image at a predefined location. And yes its compatible with all browsers, because plugin will be installed on your server.